# How to pass a variable by get into laravel and get it?

Tags: php, laravel, get, request

I have in the routs thes

```
$app->get('setChangePrice/{fecha}','AtlanticControllerChangePrice@setChangePrice');
```

How would the url to spend a date?ejm

```
http://localhost:8000/setChangePrice/fecha:2017-01-16
```

And how to get it?

```
function setChangePrice(Request $request){

        return $request->get('fecha');
}
```

I do not know how to do it! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is

```
function setChangePrice($fecha,Request $request){

    return $fecha;
}
```

> read here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#required-parameters

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is:

```
function setChangePrice(Request $request, $fecha)
{
    echo $fecha;
```